# activate display block article by class value when input radio activate?

Tags: html, css

My HTML :

```
<div id="contentapp">
    <input type="radio" name="menu" id="interest" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="menu" id="about">

    <div id="tab">
        <label for="interest">Interest</label>
        <label for="about">About</label>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
        <article class="interest">
            Interest
        </article>
        <article class="about">
            About
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS :

```
#contentapp article {
    display: none;
}
```

```
#contentapp input#interest:checked ~ article.interest{
    display: block;
}
```

this is my problem . . . : how to do it in correct way for activate display block when radio button clicked ?

Comment: Look into this. https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a div between contentapp and article. This means, you should use it in your css as well

```css
#contentapp div article {
    display: none;
}

#contentapp input#interest:checked ~ div article.interest{
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT: Here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/634ctoxw/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
#contentapp #content article {
    display: none;
}
input#interest:checked ~ #content article.interest{
    display: block;
}
```

You need to handle the ID properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```js
$(document).on('click', "input[type='radio']", function(){
  $('#contentapp article').hide();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.' + id).show();
});
```

```css
#contentapp article {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentapp">
    <input type="radio" name="menu" id="interest" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="menu" id="about">

    <div id="tab">
        <label for="interest">Interest</label>
        <label for="about">About</label>
    </div>
        <div id="content">
        <article class="interest">
            Interest
        </article>
        <article class="about">
            About
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```